# How to prevent a value from changing during rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, variables

I am making a list of lists of checkboxes. I have a ref bodyOriginal that I use to track the values I received from the database to know if they were altered or not and to activate or not the save button, and this ref is only altered on the function that makes the database request, and that function is only executed  once (I checked). When I press to check a box I use this function

```
const handleCheckboxGroup = useCallback((event, index, optionIndex) => {
const original = JSON.stringify(bodyOriginal.current[index]);
setBody(prev =>
  prev.map((item, indexPrev) => {
    if (indexPrev === index) {
      item.options[optionIndex].checked = event.target.checked;
      item.active = JSON.stringify(item) !== original; //<-
    }
    return item;
  })
);
}, []);
```

When I do it the first time it works as intended, but when I do it again the ref bodyOriginal  changes to match what the last body was, therefore making the comparison (at the "<-") always different.

If I skip the declaration of a variable and make the direct comparison:

```
JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(bodyOriginal.current[index])
```

It will always be false, because somewhere between the declaration of "original" and the comparison the variable will change to match body (despite not being called anywhere else). I was told this might be a rerender problem but I tried useCallback and useMemo and none of it seemed to stop it. How can I stop it from being altered?

Comment: Looks like you are mutating the objects in the array   item.active = , if you are modifying an item, you need to [create a new object](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays) when upating items inside an array, so it could be chaning the original item